# initialising struct by appending () even if there is no constructor defined

Tags: c++, constructor

I know that:

```
int* a= new int[3]();
```

initialises the array to 0.

But what would happen if I have a struct as below:

```
struct EmpCode
{
 int i;
};
struct emp
{
int id;
string name;
EmpCode code;
};
```

and I do `new emp *employee = new emp[3]();` Do the values are initialised here too(NOTE that I haven't defined a constructor). If yes then is this some kind of default constructor being invoked by the compiler?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, when you do `emp* employee = new emp[3]();` you get *value initialization*, which reduces to zero initialization for built-ins.

Value initialization was introduced in C++03, since the C++98 rules caused very odd behavior. It was the only new functionality in C++03. To the best of my knowledge it was proposed by Andrew Koenig.

Comment: @Cheers...so does that mean that appending () is like calling memset(0) on sizeof(employee)

Comment: @avinash: yes, but the operative word is "like". You have a `std::string` in there. It gets default-initialization, via its default constructor, not zeroed.

Comment: @Cheers...so this means that initialisation process would initialise built-ins in the default way and recursively go inside user defined type members like EmpCode till it finds built-in types and initialise them their deafult way

Answer (score -2):

No, you need to define a default constructor.